# Problem with unsaved configuration

Tags: networking, configuration, vmware, zabbix

It rarely happens to me .. But if it does then I have a problem .. I have Ubuntu on VMware on one of the hosts. Yesterday this host stopped working because one of the SFP pins was damaged, then all machines stopped working. When we managed to fix the failures, turn on ubuntu, it turned out that, for example, the entire zabbix configuration was deleted, the IP address was also changed, mumio booking .. Should I somehow save the changes in a way that I do not know?

Comment: At least you should say what version of Ubuntu so someone can try and help you.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, my fault